# Как экпортировать микс ргб с моделью, что бы он не слитал?

Tags: blender

Как экпортировать микс ргб с моделью, что бы он не слитал? При экспорти модели в моих материалах все что в миксе(вместе с ним) пропадает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вероятно, стоит уточнить, что именно подразумевается под словом «слитает».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin после экспорта модели в материале все что подсоединено к миксу просто пропадает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно запекать текстуру, в ютубе полно роликов на эту тему.

форматы в которые вы экспортируете модели, а с ними и материалы, могут не поддерживать функции(я про такие как Mix). поэтому надо запекать текстуру, то есть делать картинкой

вот отличное и короткое видео:

[[2.91] Blender Tutorial: How to Bake Procedural Textures Quick](https://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLQFopN--LY)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]